# What is advantage of implementing RSA cryptography algorithm on FPGAs?

Tags: encryption, rsa, fpga

RSA , no doubt, has several applications and is very famous. And today we use 2048-bit RSA key for security purposes. Yet, I see several research papers implementing RSA algorithm with 32-bit key (or more) on FPGAs.

http://ac.els-cdn.com/S1877050914009478/1-s2.0-S1877050914009478-main.pdf?_tid=a6e0e2de-edcd-11e5-9656-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1458390502_b193a360ee3dad04b27a38b33d3e113a

http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume92/number8/pxc3894226.pdf

What is the purpose of it? 32-bit algorithm is easily crackable.

Comment: What is your actual question here? Why on FGPA or why only 32 bits?

Comment: why on FPGA? I meant that RSA is more fitted for software programming, so, why are we implementing it through a hardware language? Even if we do, then we end up with 32 or 64 bit key RSA because it's very hard to implement 2048-bit RSA (common use) through FPGA.

Comment: No one is saying it is practical, it is just research. Researchers just research. Pure research is just that, not designed to solve a practical problem, just to learn something. You do it and then write a paper and hope it will make it into a peer reviewed journal. This is academia in action. But this is where much new things are discovered.

Comment: The advantage to implement RSA on an FPGA is to use it as an accelerator so the CPU can do others stuff in the meantime. Also, "What is the purpose of it?" is a question for the people who wrote those papers. No one is going to read through the 2 papers only to tell you what the motivations of those researchers might have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why on FPGA?

Because a hardware implementation is more efficient and offloads the CPU. That is more relevant for small devices, think IoT.

> Even if we do, then we end up with 32 or 64 bit key

That seems to be an artifact of the fact that this is research. One of those papers mentions "It is verified that this architecture support multiple key of 128bits, 256bits, and 512 bits"

Still not something I would like to use for my bank transactions but for data packets of low value, or only valuable or a short time period, even 128 bits  might be acceptable.

Comment: Still research. FPGA is not god for volume production, it is a precursor to a full-on ASIC.

Comment: 256-bit RSA might have some value, but my second-hand Mac can factor 128-bit semiprimes in a fraction of a second. (256 bits takes about 3 minutes, so still not much use.)

Comment: @squeamish - thanks, I really didn't have a calibration point handy. I suppose everything below 1024 is really just research then.

Answer (score 1):

Only Montgomery method is effective approach to RSA implementation in FPGA.

The advantage is ratio of the: technology cost, obtained bandwidth and power consumption.

This ratio for PC computer with OS is relatively weak.

Sorry for My English.